# Coordinate patch of an n-sphere?

Tags: manifolds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Analogue of spherical coordinates in $n$-dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56582/analogue-of-spherical-coordinates-in-n-dimensions)

If we take a 2-sphere of radius a, we can define $ f(z, t) = (\sqrt{a^2-z^2}\cos t,\sqrt{a^2-z^2}\sin t, z) $ it's a parametrization of the sphere, if $ 0 < t < 2\pi $ and $ |z| < a $. Also, it's a coordinate patch covering it.
Is it possible to write down such a function for a general n-sphere?

Comment: Let $z = a\cos\theta$ and $\sqrt{a^2-z^2} = a\sin\theta$, and what you're describing is spherical coordinates. Then your question becomes a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/56582/856 "Analogue of spherical coordinates in n-dimensions"). :)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot Rahul! :)