# How to efficiently calculate point coordinates on a multi-dimensional sphere?

Tags: spheres

I have the radius of the multi-dimensional sphere plus angles for each dimension-1. I know I can use sin/cos functions to obtain coordinates, but is there a computationally faster way exists?

Comment: No need to have cos and sin replaced by other formulas in  hyperspherical coordinates defined with (n-1) angles (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/56582). Cosines and sines should be first tabulated (and hopefully interpolated later), i.e. computed and arranged into a table, e.g., all $cos(k\pi/10^4)$ for $k=0 \cdots 10^4$, it's very efficient to access to any value.

Comment: Yes, you are right about look-up tables, but I was looking for precise solution different to a well-known serial multiplication of sines/cosines.

Comment: I am sorry because there is a general parameterization that I has completely forgotten: it is through the stereographic coordinates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)