# Using spherical coordinates to bound $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \|x-y\|_2 ^{-a}dy$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is it possible to bound
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \|x-y\|_2 ^{-a}dy$$
with
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^a}dr$$
by using spherical coordinates?

For $n=3$ this is clear, but what about $n>3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Hyperspherical_coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Hyperspherical_coordinates). See an example of application in [Volume of Region in 5D Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50953/volume-of-region-in-5d-space/51406#51406).