# n-dimensional volume of a hypersphere

Tags: manifolds, volume, spheres

I am currently trying to work out the n-dimensional volume of

$$ \mathbf{S}^n_+ := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:||x||=1 , x_{n+1}>0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $$

Using the fact that $\mathbf{S}^n_+$ is an $n$-manifold, I used:

$$\psi: B^n_1 \longrightarrow \mathbf{S}^n_+ $$

$$x \mapsto (x_1,\dots,x_n,\sqrt{1-||x||^2} ) $$

as a parameterization, with $B^n_1$ being a $n$-ball with radius $1$ . And the fact that

$$Vol_n(\mathbf{S}^n_+)=\int_ {B^n_1} \sqrt{det(\psi^{’T}\psi’)}d\lambda$$

But I have problems evaluating the integral, I have proceed until this step, but don‘t know how to get further:

$$\int_ {B^n_1} \sqrt{det(\psi^{’T}\psi’)}d\lambda= \int_ {B^n_1} \sqrt{1+||grad(\psi)||^2}d\lambda=$$

$$\int_ {B^n_1} \sqrt{1+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{1-||x||}}d\lambda= \int_ {B^n_1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-||x||}}d\lambda= \dots $$

I would be glad to get some help and/or pointers.

Comment: Why not find the volume of the $(n+1)$-ball of radius $r$ and differentiate?

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2602694) is similar in execution, but [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/388332) is simpler. These give the volume. We can then differentiate to get the surface area.